# Can fingerprints be verified over USSD?

Tags: authentication, identity, fingerprint, ussd

I work for a public sector body in West Africa where we need to establish a method to establish identity in areas that do not have a data connection.

We have fingerprints of our members in our database.

Is it possible to verify fingerprints over a USSD connection? Basically , have a mechanism of collecting the fingerprints using a basic smartphone+scanner combination, and validate it against the information in our database ... but do this without a data connection.

Any help will be much appreciated ...

Comment: help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542163/verifinger-11-2-invalid-sample-resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Database of fingerprints could be put, and synchronize when data is available (Wifi, mobile, ...), on each devices (smartphone).
   Match could be done one device with this kind of SDK http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger-technical-specifications.html (3000 fingerprint match by second)

**Disadvantage** Could be very dangerous if a device is stolen or lost and hacked to get database.

2. You could use SMS. The smallest format of fingerprint is FMC CS (Compact Size) for [2 fingerprints max size is 512 Bytes](http://egov.eletsonline.com/2008/11/fingerprint-templates/) and for [1 fingerprint max size 241 Bytes](http://support.id3.eu/en/getFile_62/productDoc.htm). If you convert it to Base64 then for one fingerprint it'will be around:

> 241 * 4/3 = 322 bytes

So you could send multiple SMS (around 5) with this template and receive response by SMS. Each SMS have a transaction identifier, SMS total + current number, and a part of fingerprint.

> 1 SMS = 160 char, 322 bytes (in base64) = 644 char, 644 char / 160 = 4 SMS

Comment: We also have a unique identifier number associated with each person, could combination of fingerprint and unique identifier simplify or make this process of matching more efficient?

Comment: Yes of course instead  of match current fingerprint against all fingerprints in database; you could only match current fingerprint against identified person fingerprint